# O que são os serviços de aplicação e de domínio na Onion Architecture?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, arquitetura-de-software

Na Onion Architecture existe o *core* (miolo) da aplicação que inclui os objetos do domínio, os Domain Services e os Application Services:

[image: Onion architecture]

Estou em dúvida sobre o que são os dois últimos (domain services e application services). Alguém teria um exemplo em Java dos objetos dessas camadas para demonstrar? Ou pelo menos a definição do que vai neles?

Comment: A arquitetura que te faz chorar.

Comment: @Maniero como é que _cê bola_ essas piadas ruins tão rápido? :P

Comment: @Bacco ah, achei que era boa... :) Mas é mais antiga que andar pra frente, eu só fui o primeiro a lembrar :)

Comment: @Bacco I see what you did there

Comment: @Piovezan e eu vi até o que você não viu :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O objetivo principal de qualquer camada **Service** é prover um conjunto de métodos que permitam a execução de tarefas no seu software. Pra executar tais tarefas os services geralmente precisam interagir com diversos outros elementos do seu software que ficam nas camadas mais internas da Onion Architecture.

Sendo assim:

A camada **Application Service**:

- Fornece para o usuário (através das interfaces) operações que o seu software pode executar, e controla a execução dessas operações através de chamadas a métodos de objetos das outras camadas (domínio, infraestrutura, etc.). É importante dizer que a Application Service **não contém regras de negócios ou conhecimento do domínio**, sendo assim, ela apenas coordena as chamadas a métodos de outras camadas e mantém o estado que reflete o progresso de uma operação para o usuário.

A camada **Domain Services**:

- Fornece para a **Application Service** métodos que permitam a execução de operações sobre os objetos de Domínio (camada mais interna). Embora seja seja comum representar grande parte dos conceitos e regras principais do negócio aqui, o ideal é que esses detalhes sejam representados diretamente nas classes de domínio (Domain Model). Sendo assim, o objetivo adequado para essa camada é a chamar e controlar a execução de métodos dos objetos do Domain Model **quando não é trivial ou lógico  declarar um método diretamente no modelo de domínio**

**Exemplo**

Pois bem, vamos a um exemplo prático. Suponha que temos um software de caixa eletrônico que possui apenas a opção de transferência entre contas.

A primeira coisa a se fazer é declarar os elementos do domínio. Nesse caso, precisamos de uma classe *Conta*, e essa classe deve permitir o acesso a informações de saldo e também meios para podermos adicionar e remover saldo. Então temos a seguinte classe:

```
public class Conta {

    private Float saldo;

    public Conta(Float saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    public Float getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    // Para deixar mais simples não faço validações de saldo
    public void debitar(Float quantia) {
        saldo = saldo - quantia;
    }

    public void creditar(Float quantia) {
        saldo = saldo + quantia;
    }
}
```

Essa classe pertence a camada de **Domain Model**, pois ela contém o coração do negócio, ou seja, as regras essenciais para o funcionamento do seu caixa eletrônico.

Pois bem, agora precisamos fornecer uma maneira de realizar uma transferência. Se pararmos para pensar um pouco, não faz muito sentido termos uma operação de transferência dentro da própria conta, pois uma transferência envolve duas contas, porém faz muito sentido termos um **serviço de transferências**. O papel desse serviço seria manipular dois objetos *Conta* com o objetivo de creditar e debitar as contas adequadamente. Então vamos criar nosso serviço de transferência.

```
public class TransferenciaServices {

    public boolean transferir(Float quantia, Conta contaOrigem, Conta contaDestino) {

        if (contaOrigem.getSaldo() < quantia) {
            return false;
        } else {
            contaOrigem.debitar(quantia);
            contaDestino.creditar(quantia);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Percebe-se então que a nossa classe *TransferenciaServices* é uma classe da camada de *Domain Services*, pois ela coordena os objetos *Conta* do domínio.

Pois bem, ja temos o nosso domínio completamente implementado. Só nos resta agora fornecer ao usuário uma maneira de executar uma transferência.

Antes de prosseguir vamos supor que o passo a passo para realizar uma transferencia seja:

1. Selecionar a conta destino
2. Inserir a quantia
3. Finalizar a transferência

Vamos supor também que:

a) O sistema possui um banco de dados no qual as contas são obtidas e salvas

b) As etapas de 1 a 2 são feitas em sequência na tela do caixa e na etapa 3 o sistema já possui todos os dados de *Conta* e quantia necessários para a transferência.

Prosseguindo. Portanto nossa camada **Application Services** deve possuir serviços que permitam que o usuário, através de uma interface, execute uma transferência. Por ser da camada de aplicação, esse serviço também deve ser responsável por chamar os métodos corretos dos serviços do domínio e também deve ser responsável por acessar e salvar corretamente os dados no banco de dados. Então temos para a nossa última camada, a seguinte classe:

```
public class TransferenciaApplicationServices {

    // Dependências necessárias para que o serviço possa ser executado
    private ContasDatabase database;
    private TransferenciaServices transferenciaServices;

    public TransferenciaApplicationServices(ContasDatabase database, TransferenciaServices transferenciaServices) {
            this.database = database;
            this.transferenciaServices = transferenciaServices;  
    }

    public boolean transferir(Float quantia, Conta contaOrigem, Conta contaDestino) {

        boolean transferidoComSucesso = transferenciaServices.transferir(quantia, contaOrigem, contaDestino);

        if (transferidoComSucesso) {
            // Salva as contas com saldo atualizado no banco 
            database.atualizarConta(contaOrigem);
            database.atualizarConta(contaDestino);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Como pode ser visto, a responsabilidade da *TransferenciaApplicationServices* é coordenar a execução de métodos do banco de dados e da TransferenciaServices com o objetivo de garantir que uma transferência seja executada com sucesso.

É isso, espero que tenha ajudado a entender :)

Comment: Ajudou sim e de forma muito clara! Responda mais vezes! :)