# Domain Driven Design, qual a diferença entre Domain Services, Infrastructure Services e Application Services

Tags: design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software, ddd

É correto afirmar que as regras de negócios devem ser escritas dentro da Domain Service? Se sim, como uma entidade de domínio não é anêmica, ela também implementa suas regras de negócios, então a Domain Service serviria somente para orquestrar as chamadas dessas regras, correto? E a Infrastructure Services e Application Services, quais suas finalidades?
Poderiam me explicar essas áreas, se possível com exemplos?

Comment: Apenas um comentário a respeito de Transferência e do ponto de atenção que tanto Vernom quanto Evans fazem com veemência: Evite criar serviços de domínio desnecessários. Muitas vezes é mais interessante avaliar se o orquestrador em si não pode ser uma entidade. É o que eles chamam de expor comportamento através de entidade. Nesse caso, o TransferenciaService poderia ser uma entidade Transferencia com possui referências para conta de origem e destino. Vale lembrar que em casos do mundo real, isso será uma necessidade de negócio para que sejam registrados em histórico todas as movimentações banc

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Bem, a resposta pra suas perguntas é bem parecida com a resposta pra [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360092/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-servi%C3%A7os-de-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-de-dom%C3%ADnio-na-onion-architecture). Como eu acabei respondendo ela vou tomar a liberdade de reaproveita-la e complementa-la pro seu caso :)

**Application Service**:

- Fornece para o usuário (através das interfaces) operações que o seu software pode executar, e controla a execução dessas operações através de chamadas a métodos de objetos das outras camadas (domínio, infraestrutura, etc.). É importante dizer que a Application Service **não contém regras de negócios ou conhecimento do domínio**, sendo assim, ela apenas coordena as chamadas a métodos de outras camadas e mantém o estado que reflete o progresso de uma operação para o usuário.

**Domain Services**:

- Fornece para a **Application Service** métodos que permitam a execução de operações sobre os objetos de Domínio (camada mais interna). Embora seja comum representar grande parte dos conceitos e regras principais do negócio aqui, o ideal é que esses detalhes sejam representados diretamente nos Domain Models.
  Sendo assim, o Domain Service deve chamar e controlar a execução de métodos dos objetos do Domain Model **quando não é trivial ou lógico  declarar um método diretamente no modelo de domínio**

**Infrastructure Services**:

- Fornece métodos que permitem a execução de operações sobre a infraestrutura na qual o software está sendo executado. Isso significa que esses serviços tem conhecimento sobre detalhes das implementações concretas da infraestrutura tais como: acesso a bancos de dados, acesso a rede, controle de operações de IO, acesso a hardware etc. Geralmente esse service é utilizado pelos Application Services para complementar e auxiliar suas operações, por exemplo, fornecer um método que permita a criação e controle de um buffer para realizar download de arquivos.

**Exemplo**

Suponha que temos um software de caixa eletrônico que possui apenas a opção de transferência entre contas.

A primeira coisa a se fazer é declarar os elementos do domínio. Nesse caso, precisamos de uma classe *Conta*, e essa classe deve permitir o acesso a informações de saldo e também meios para podermos adicionar e remover saldo. Então temos a seguinte classe:

```
public class Conta {

    private Float saldo;

    public Conta(Float saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    public Float getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    // Para deixar mais simples não faço validações de saldo
    public void debitar(Float quantia) {
        saldo = saldo - quantia;
    }

    public void creditar(Float quantia) {
        saldo = saldo + quantia;
    }
}
```

Pois bem, agora precisamos fornecer uma maneira de realizar uma transferência. Se pararmos para pensar um pouco, não faz muito sentido termos uma operação de transferência dentro da própria conta, pois uma transferência envolve duas contas, porém faz muito sentido termos um **serviço de transferências**. O papel desse serviço seria manipular dois objetos *Conta* com o objetivo de creditar e debitar as contas adequadamente. Então vamos criar nosso serviço de transferência.

```
public class TransferenciaServices {

    public boolean transferir(Float quantia, Conta contaOrigem, Conta contaDestino) {

        if (contaOrigem.getSaldo() < quantia) {
            return false;
        } else {
            contaOrigem.debitar(quantia);
            contaDestino.creditar(quantia);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Pois bem, ja temos o nosso domínio completamente implementado. Só nos resta agora fornecer ao usuário uma maneira de executar uma transferência.

Mas antes de continuarmos, suponhamos que por motivos de acessibilidade, o caixa eletrônico deva emitir um sinal sonoro em caso de sucesso na transferência. Suponhamos também que esse sinal sonoro pode ser emitido através de chamadas a métodos de uma API que o fabricante do caixa eletrônico nos forneceu. Perceba que a manipulação dessa API e emissão de sinal sonoro são detalhes da infraestrutura na qual o software está executando, e portanto, eles devem pertencer a Infrastructure Services. Nesse caso, poderiamos ter a seguinte classe:

```
//Serviço específico para manipulação de sons da infraestrutura
public class SoundServices {

        /* ... */

        // Api do fabricante
        private ApiCaixaEletronico apiCaixaEletronico;

        public void emitirSinal() {

            //Exemplo de possivel função da api do fabricante que permite emitir
            // um sinal sonoro num determinado volume em decibéis (dB)
            int volumeDecibeis = 60; 
            apiCaixaEletronico.emitirSom(volumeDecibeis);
        }
    }
```

Bem, agora só nos resta o **Application Services**. Como visto, ele deve possuir serviços que permitam que o usuário execute uma transferência. Esse serviço também deve ser responsável por chamar os métodos corretos dos serviços do domínio, ser responsável por acessar e salvar corretamente os dados no banco de dados e também emitir o sinal sonoro após a conclusão da transferência. Então temos a seguinte classe:

```
public class TransferenciaApplicationServices {

    // Dependências necessárias para que o serviço possa ser executado
    private ContasDatabase database;
    private TransferenciaServices transferenciaServices;
    private SoundServices soundServices;

    /* ... */

    public boolean transferir(Float quantia, Conta contaOrigem, Conta contaDestino) {

        boolean transferidoComSucesso = transferenciaServices.transferir(quantia, contaOrigem, contaDestino);

        if (transferidoComSucesso) {
            // Salva as contas com saldo atualizado no banco 
            database.atualizarConta(contaOrigem);
            database.atualizarConta(contaDestino);

            // Emite sinal sonoro de sucesso
            soundServices.emitirSinal();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Como pode ser visto, a responsabilidade da *TransferenciaApplicationServices* é coordenar a execução de métodos dos repositórios, da infraestrutura e do TransferenciaServices com o objetivo de garantir que uma transferência seja executada com sucesso.

Comment: Excelente explicação! Muito obrigado por ter fornecido exemplos também, facilitou muito o entendimento. Vamos em frente!